# What is the best way to create a TradingView alert that triggers every time the price moves a relative 25%?

Tags: pine-script

I want to make an alert that triggers every time that the price of an asset crosses the white lines:

[image]

The white lines represents a periodical decrease of 25%. For example, the yellow line is the first value that we will use to calculate the rest of the lines. Since the first value is on 2.099, the 25% decrease is on 1.574. Then the 25% decrease of 1.574 is 1.181, and so on.

I've already tried to use the alert creator on TradingView but it seems it just let me calculate a % move in a single bar, and I want it to trigger no matter how many bars does it take to reach the white values.

Is there a way to consider all the white lines as a group, and create an alertcondition() function in PineScript so I can make it trigger in a single condition? Or what is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
indicator("% Retracements", overlay = true)

start_price = input.price(100, title = "start price level", confirm = true)
perc = input.float(25, title = "Percentage Retracement", minval = 0, maxval = 100) / 100
num_ret = input.int(5, title = "number of retracement levels", minval = 1)
wait = input.bool(false, title = "wait for bar close?")

var float[] levels_array = array.new_float()
var line[] white_lines_array = array.new_line()
var label[] label_prices_array = array.new_label()
var line start_line = line.new(x1 = bar_index, y1 = start_price, x2 = bar_index + 1, y2 = start_price, color = color.yellow, width = 2, extend = extend.both)
var label start_label = label.new(x = bar_index, y = start_price, style = label.style_label_left, size = size.small, color = #00000000, text = str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(start_price)) + "\n", textcolor = color.yellow)

if barstate.isfirst
    float level_price = start_price
    for i = 0 to num_ret - 1
        level_price := level_price * (1 - perc)
        array.push(levels_array, level_price)
        array.push(white_lines_array, line.new(x1 = bar_index, y1 = level_price, x2 = bar_index + 1, y2 = level_price, extend = extend.both, color = color.white, width = 2))
        array.push(label_prices_array, label.new(x = bar_index, y = level_price, style = label.style_label_left, size = size.small, color = #00000000, text = str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(level_price)) + "\n", textcolor = color.white))

if barstate.islast
    line.set_x2(start_line, bar_index + 1)
    label.set_x(start_label, bar_index + 1)
    for i = 0 to num_ret - 1
        line_i = array.get(white_lines_array, i)
        label_i = array.get(label_prices_array, i)
        line.set_x2(line_i, bar_index + 1)
        label.set_x(label_i, bar_index + 1)

if wait ? barstate.isrealtime and barstate.isconfirmed : barstate.isrealtime
    bool level_crossed = false
    string alert_text = na
    for i = 0 to num_ret - 1
        price_i = array.get(levels_array, i)
        if (open < price_i and close > price_i) or (open > price_i and close < price_i)
            level_crossed := true
            if na(alert_text)
                alert_text := "Crossed : " + str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(price_i))
            else
                alert_text += " & " + str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(price_i))
    if level_crossed
        alert(alert_text, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```